# Solr spellcheck problems

Tags: solr, spell-checking, search-suggestion

I have a weird problem with the spellcheck suggestions of Solr.

I search for a term like this (a product-number for example): 08p17a6

With this term, i find documents in my index.

I have enabled spellcheck=true. So besides documents, solr also gives me a spellcheck suggestion in the xml response:

```
<lst name="spellcheck">
    <lst name="suggestions">
        <lst name="p17a6">
            <int name="numFound">1</int>
            <int name="startOffset">2</int>
            <int name="endOffset">7</int>
            <arr name="suggestion">
                <str>08p17a6</str>
            </arr>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

Solr takes of the first to numbers of my search term, and gives me a suggestion based on "p17a6". I don't understand why he cuts of the first two numbers for his suggestion.

Things will get more weird, if i enable spellcheck.collate:

```
<lst name="spellcheck">
    <lst name="suggestions">
        <lst name="p17a6">
            <int name="numFound">1</int>
            <int name="startOffset">2</int>
            <int name="endOffset">7</int>
            <arr name="suggestion">
                <str>08p17a6</str>
            </arr>
        </lst>
        <str name="collation">0808p17a6</str>
    </lst>
</lst>
```

I need to use spellcheck.collate for suggestsions on multiple search terms. But as you can see, the xml response suggests me to use "0808p17a6".

Does anyone know how this happens?

Edit:

**Here is my schema configuration regarding the spellcheck:**

```
<field name="spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
<copyField source="title"    dest="spell" />
<copyField source="subTitle" dest="spell" />
<copyField source="content"  dest="spell" />
```

**The source fields of the copyfields are configured like this:**

```
<field name="title"       type="text"   indexed="true"  stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true" />
<field name="subTitle"    type="text"   indexed="true"  stored="true" termVectors="true" omitNorms="true" />
<field name="content"     type="text"   indexed="true"  stored="true" termVectors="true" />
```

**This is the configuration for the analyzers:**

```
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"
        />
        <!-- best practice (currently) for synonyms is to add them by
            expansions during index time
        -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="german/synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
            add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
            analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="german/stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" protected="german/protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"
        />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="german/stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" protected="german/protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<!-- Setup simple analysis for spell checking -->
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>

        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="german/synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="german/stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />

        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="german/stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Could you please post also how you analyze, tokenize and then filter the token on the field ? Most probably the problem is there.

Comment: @Silenteh i edited my post and inserted my schema configuration. Maybe you can have a look at this, i also think some filter causes this. But i don't know which one affects the spellchecker.